# Testing angular http service calls against a running backend

Tags: angular, protractor, karma-runner, angular-cli, angular-services

I need to test my angular services - especially the http calls - against a running backend (that is without mocking the backend).

I don't need real end to end tests: (UI --> backend); only for my http services to call the backend: (ng http services --> backend)

I have tried with Karma first but it is currently not possible to specify a 
proxy configuration (e.g. `ng test --ssl --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`) and I quickly ran into CORS issues. It was also very difficult to change the backend URL: I had to implement an interceptor in order to change the URL.

I then tried to use `ng e2e` testing but ran into the following error:

```js
[11:21:06] E/launcher - Error: ReferenceError: Zone is not defined
```

My test is as follows:

```js
  it('should call API', inject([FunctionnService], (service: FunctionnService) => {
    service.findFunctionns().subscribe({
      next: value => console.log(value),
      error: err => console.log(err),
      complete: () => console.log('complete')
    });
  //No assertions for the time being
  }));
```

here is the service under test:

```js
@Injectable()
export class FunctionnService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(URLs) private urls: UrlsApi) {
  }

  findFunctionns(): Observable<Functionn[]> {
    return this.http.get<{ functionns: Functionn[] }>(this.urls.api.functions)
      .map(response => response.functionns);
  }
  ...
```

Can anyone please provide advice?

Comment: Why not mock the backend. With real calls, tests will be always dependent on a running backend server

Comment: The thing you're trying to do is unit/integration test, and Protractor (e2e) was not meant for that. With properly performed unit tests for both frontend and backend there is no need to test a service with real backend, this is redundant and (as you witnessed) can be cumbersome. Any way, I don't see why a proxy couldn't be set with custom Karma config. Btw, considering that there is `URLs` service, is there something that prevents base url from being set there? I wouldn't call interceptor 'very difficult', too; it's reasonable solution in a situation like this one.

Comment: We have other tests that mock the backend but we need to test that the contract between the backend and the frontend is fulfilled. We recently met a bug when one of the backend endpoint was modified but the frontend service was not adapted accordingly: all backend & frontend tests ran successfully but because we had no test to guarantee the backend/frontend interaction, the bug was not caught and we ran into a 400 error that no test was able to catch...

Comment: @estus can you provide pointers as to how to configure a proxy in karma? I have tried: `proxies: {
      '/api/': 'http://localhost:8080/',
    },` in my karma conf to no avail.

Comment: Yes, this is how it's expected to be done, https://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/config/configuration-file.html . Make sure that Karma loads proper config file. Consider addressing this in separate question if your real problem is Karma proxy.

Comment: As for frontend/backend integration, this is exactly what Protractor e2e/integration tests are for. They can be much looser than unit tests, just roughly check that everything works.

Comment: Somehow, with the above configuration, I run into CORS issues. I don't have these CORS issue when I use ng cli's proxy option...

Comment: I see your point estus but I don't need to test all the UI layer. Just the service layer against a running backend...

Comment: I'd suggest to inspect Chrome network tab when Karma runs and investigate how it's possible. This will possibly require http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to replicate the problem.

Comment: OK @estus Thanks. Will do.

Comment: In the meantime if anyone has already had this requirement for a angular service to backend testing, please feel free to share your experience and solutions.

Comment: @balteo I meant some general e2e tests like 'ok, the page loaded normally, so AJAX works'. And it's not uncommon to build separate apps for integration test cases that contain minimal or no UI. Any way, since Karma has same facilities for proxies as Protractor and is suitable for this sort of integration tests, I'd suggest to go Karma and figure it out.